# Pandas - Add a column to uniquely identify each group after group-by

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, gps, gis

I want to have a column(Similarity_Index) against each group after group-by using columns `s_lat, s_lng, d_lat, d_lng`, so that they are identified uniquely. My DataFrame looks like this:

```
+--------+-------+--------+--------+--------+------------------+------+-------+------+--------------------+-------+---------+
| Id     | s_lat | s_lng  | d_lat  | d_lng  |        TT        |  T   | Esti2 | Est1 |     time_diff      | diff  | Cluster |
+--------+-------+--------+--------+--------+------------------+------+-------+------+--------------------+-------+---------+
|  67607 | 63.42 | 10.387 | 63.425 | 10.441 |             10.2 | 4.33 |    11 |  4.4 | -0.800000000000001 | -0.07 |       0 |
|  70720 | 63.42 | 10.387 | 63.425 | 10.441 | 9.03333333333333 | 4.36 |    11 |  4.4 |  -1.96666666666667 | -0.04 |       0 |
|  68394 | 63.42 | 10.387 | 63.436 | 10.399 | 15.1833333333333 | 2.66 |    10 |  2.7 |   5.18333333333333 | -0.04 |       0 |
|  67340 | 63.42 | 10.387 | 63.436 | 10.399 | 8.91666666666667 | 2.44 |    10 |  2.7 |  -1.08333333333333 | -0.26 |       0 |
|  72363 | 63.42 | 10.387 | 63.436 | 10.399 | 9.91666666666667 | 2.47 |    10 |  2.7 | -0.083333333333334 | -0.23 |       0 |
|  70401 | 63.42 | 10.387 | 63.436 | 10.399 |             7.85 | 2.67 |    10 |  2.7 |              -2.15 | -0.03 |       0 |
|  70695 | 63.42 | 10.387 | 63.436 | 10.399 | 11.6166666666667 | 3.24 |    10 |  2.7 |   1.61666666666667 |  0.54 |       0 |
|  69698 | 63.42 | 10.387 | 63.436 | 10.399 | 8.91666666666667 | 2.47 |    10 |  2.7 |  -1.08333333333333 | -0.23 |       0 |
|  70793 | 63.42 | 10.387 | 63.436 | 10.399 |            11.85 | 2.52 |    10 |  2.7 |               1.85 | -0.18 |       0 |
|  67150 | 63.42 | 10.387 | 63.411 | 10.402 | 4.01666666666667 | 1.68 |     6 |  1.7 |  -1.98333333333333 | -0.02 |       0 |
|  69934 | 63.42 | 10.387 | 63.411 | 10.402 | 4.56666666666667 | 1.69 |     6 |  1.7 |  -1.43333333333333 | -0.01 |       0 |
+--------+-------+--------+--------+--------+------------------+------+-------+------+--------------------+-------+---------+
```

`s_lat | s_lng  | d_lat  | d_lng` define start and destination lat and lng, I am trying to pair the similar trips based on the locations, what is the best way to achieve it.

Desired Output looks something like this

```
+--------+-------+--------+--------+--------+------------------+------+-------+------+--------------------+-------+---------+------------------+
| TourId | s_lat | s_lng  | d_lat  | d_lng  |        TT        |  T   | Esti2 | Est1 |     time_diff      | diff  | Cluster | Similarity_index |
+--------+-------+--------+--------+--------+------------------+------+-------+------+--------------------+-------+---------+------------------+
|  67607 | 63.42 | 10.387 | 63.425 | 10.441 |             10.2 | 4.33 |    11 |  4.4 | -0.800000000000001 | -0.07 |       0 | A                |
|  70720 | 63.42 | 10.387 | 63.425 | 10.441 | 9.03333333333333 | 4.36 |    11 |  4.4 |  -1.96666666666667 | -0.04 |       0 | A                |
|  68394 | 63.42 | 10.387 | 63.436 | 10.399 | 15.1833333333333 | 2.66 |    10 |  2.7 |   5.18333333333333 | -0.04 |       0 | B                |
|  67340 | 63.42 | 10.387 | 63.436 | 10.399 | 8.91666666666667 | 2.44 |    10 |  2.7 |  -1.08333333333333 | -0.26 |       0 | B                |
|  72363 | 63.42 | 10.387 | 63.436 | 10.399 | 9.91666666666667 | 2.47 |    10 |  2.7 | -0.083333333333334 | -0.23 |       0 | B                |
|  70401 | 63.42 | 10.387 | 63.436 | 10.399 |             7.85 | 2.67 |    10 |  2.7 |              -2.15 | -0.03 |       0 | B                |
|  70695 | 63.42 | 10.387 | 63.436 | 10.399 | 11.6166666666667 | 3.24 |    10 |  2.7 |   1.61666666666667 |  0.54 |       0 | B                |
|  69698 | 63.42 | 10.387 | 63.436 | 10.399 | 8.91666666666667 | 2.47 |    10 |  2.7 |  -1.08333333333333 | -0.23 |       0 | B                |
|  70793 | 63.42 | 10.387 | 63.436 | 10.399 |            11.85 | 2.52 |    10 |  2.7 |               1.85 | -0.18 |       0 | B                |
|  67150 | 63.42 | 10.387 | 63.411 | 10.402 | 4.01666666666667 | 1.68 |     6 |  1.7 |  -1.98333333333333 | -0.02 |       0 | C                |
|  69934 | 63.42 | 10.387 | 63.411 | 10.402 | 4.56666666666667 | 1.69 |     6 |  1.7 |  -1.43333333333333 | -0.01 |       0 | C                |
+--------+-------+--------+--------+--------+------------------+------+-------+------+--------------------+-------+---------+------------------+
```

Comment: I'm not sure I can understand what is the calculation you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am looking for something adding an indicator at the end that these two destinations are the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this

```
import string
d = dict(enumerate(list(string.ascii_uppercase))) # will give 26 unique values
df['S_I']=df.groupby(['s_lat','s_lng','d_lat','d_lng'], sort = False).ngroup().map(d)
```

If there can be more than 26 unique groups, you can use the following code for generating list `d`

```
from itertools import product
combs= [''.join(i) for i in product(string.ascii_uppercase, repeat = 2)]
d=dict(enumerate(combs))

#Change the number for 'repeat' as needed.
 with 2, you get 676 unique combinations like "'AA','AB','AC'..."
 with 3, you get 17576 unique combinations like "'AAA','AAB','AAC'..."
```

**Output**

```
Id  s_lat   s_lng   d_lat   d_lng   TT  T   Esti2   Est1    time_diff   diff    Cluster     S_I
0   67607   63.42   10.387  63.425  10.441  10.200000   4.33    11  4.4     -0.800000   -0.07   0   A
1   70720   63.42   10.387  63.425  10.441  9.033333    4.36    11  4.4     -1.966667   -0.04   0   A
2   68394   63.42   10.387  63.436  10.399  15.183333   2.66    10  2.7     5.183333    -0.04   0   B
3   67340   63.42   10.387  63.436  10.399  8.916667    2.44    10  2.7     -1.083333   -0.26   0   B
4   72363   63.42   10.387  63.436  10.399  9.916667    2.47    10  2.7     -0.083333   -0.23   0   B
5   70401   63.42   10.387  63.436  10.399  7.850000    2.67    10  2.7     -2.150000   -0.03   0   B
6   70695   63.42   10.387  63.436  10.399  11.616667   3.24    10  2.7     1.616667    0.54    0   B
7   69698   63.42   10.387  63.436  10.399  8.916667    2.47    10  2.7     -1.083333   -0.23   0   B
8   70793   63.42   10.387  63.436  10.399  11.850000   2.52    10  2.7     1.850000    -0.18   0   B
9   67150   63.42   10.387  63.411  10.402  4.016667    1.68    6   1.7     -1.983333   -0.02   0   C
10  69934   63.42   10.387  63.411  10.402  4.566667    1.69    6   1.7     -1.433333   -0.01   0   C
```

Comment: can you suggest an edit to my question to make it more understandable

Comment: is there a better way for to mark them similar in S_I column as alphabets are only 26 and will run out for large data sets?

Comment: You can use numbers. If that is ok, the code is just one line & you don't even havce to import the library. The code will be just `df['S_I']=df.groupby(['s_lat','s_lng','d_lat','d_lng'], sort = False).ngroup()`

Comment: @M_S_N Regarding your question about making your question more understandable, I think you can change the heading to something like "Add a column to uniquely identify each group after group-by". IN the explanation, you can say, "I want to have a column(S_I) where each group after group-by using columns x,y,z, are identified uniquely". Then you put the input & output dataframes. That should be enough.

Comment: Updated the code to get Alphabetical combinations of more than just 26.